# Create automation script for existing Azure Resource Group and all contained Resources

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I have an existing resource group containing a handful of resources created via the Azure Portal. I want to create the JSON template to allow a possible future deployment of an exact replica of the resource group and its contents.

I'm aware of the 'Automation' menu option for the Resource Group, however the resulting template doesn't capture the changes to configuration made after the creation of each resource. It also doesn't include some features (e.g. deployment slots).

Using the Azure Resource Explorer (https://resources.azure.com/) I can generate the complete and up-to-date JSON for each resource, but I can't see a way to recursively generate the JSON for the entire Resource Group.

Is there currently a means to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible and there are properties that cannot be captured with rest api (from the top of my head - azure automation modules). I wouldn't rely on the approach you are advocating for.

The proper way would be to make changes to the arm template and deploy it. so do it the other way around, not the way you want it to be.

Comment: Shame as the Azure Resource Explorer contains everything I need. I guess I will need to use the exported template from the Azure portal and then add the additional config by hand from the JSON displayed in the Resource Explorer...